# Is there a hook for comment author link?

Tags: comments

There is an author_link hook which is very useful for posts and bios; however, I don't see a hook for comment author link. Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other two answers probably answer your question, but here's a way look at WordPress source code to be able to determine for yourself whether a certain hook exists for your purposes.

You ask whether there is a hook for the comment author link. So let's look at the source for that function: [`comment_author_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_author_link/).

We see that there's not really much to that function. It just echos the output of [`get_comment_author_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_link/). So let's look at that function.

It does some stuff and then returns the filtered results of [`get_comment_author_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_comment_author_link/). So you could use that filter to modify the output of `comment_author_link()`.

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', function( $return, $author, $comment_id ){
  if( 'example' === $author ) {
    $return = '<a href="https://example.com/">Example</a>';
  }
  return $return;
}, 10, 3 );
```

But I have a feeling that you want to modify the URL of the comment author. If that's the case, we see that `get_comment_author_link()` calls [`get_comment_author_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_url/) to determine the author.

And in that function we see that it returns the filtered results of [`get_comment_author_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_comment_author_url/).

So if you want to change the URL of the comment author link, you could do something like:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', function( $url, $id, $comment ){
  if( 'example' === $comment->comment_author ) {
    $url = 'https://example.com/';
  }
  return $url;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd avoid using anonymous callbacks because removing them can be complicated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a filter hook like author_link hook.

```
get_comment_author_link()
```

Details info about the above filter hook.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_comment_author_link/

There are a lot of built-in functions at wordpress.

```
<?php comment_author_url_link('linktext', 'before', 'after'); ?>
```

Let's have a look the functions related to comments.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author_url_link

I hope you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `get_comment_author_url` ?